# Windows custom system variables in save/open boxes

Tags: windows, filesystems, environment-variables, explorer

For many years I've been using the windows custom system path to mapping folders and files to be accessible through RUN box. I put the main folder path in the PATH field of Environment Vars and so I can type the subfolder name in the RUN and access it.

Environment Vars:

[image: RUN box]

Per example, I can type "cronos" in the RUN box and access a folder with this name, within "b:\wampp\www".  I would like to use these variables in the Windows Explorer, on save / open boxes, in the same way that the %USERPROFILE% and %PATH% variables are used. I think that %cronos% should work, but it is not recognized.

var on save box:

[image: var on save box]

Has anyone used the vars in this way? Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use it in this way, you need add "cronos" full path to `Path` variable in your system, and to do the same with all vars that you want.